# Typescript using Map with a generic type in the value

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
class A<T> {
  constructor(public value: T) {}
}

const map = new Map();
map.set('a', new A('a'));
map.set('b', new A(1));

const a = map.get('a');
const b = map.get('b');
```

Currently, `a` and `b` are inferred as `any`. If I change it to:

```
const map = new Map<string, A<????>>();
```

I need to pass the generic type of `A`, but then I'm losing the `value` property type. There is a way to achieve it?

```
const a = map.get('a') // should be inferred as A<string>
const b = map.get('b') // should be inferred as A<number>
```

Comment: `Map` is typed like `Record`: all the values must be of the same type.  Even if you had a custom typing for `Map` where each key had its own value type (which sounds like you should use an `interface` and a plain-old object instead of `Map`) the type system doesn't model mutations well.

Comment: @jcalz it will work with a plain-old object? Didn't work for me either

Comment: @undefined progressively mutating the type of a value is not something the type system does well.  You could progressively *narrow* it, which only works if you never plan to unset/delete/change the values at a given key.   If that's all right I could give you a possible implementation, but even so it's not wonderful.  Ideally for TS you just use a plain object with the key-value pairs set at the beginning, and read it later.

Comment: @jcalz I only need to set or delete a property from an object. Can you provide a solution with a plain object?

Comment: Setting/getting is fine, deleting is not.  Well, unless you're okay with the value always being `| undefined` when you read it.  Let me see what I can write up

Comment: that wasn't clear to me, i mean, i don't get that you want to use a map like `new Map()`, if you don't know the actual types at compile time, then you should use `format type parameters`.  I guess if you don't specify the actual types (the so called `actual type parameters`) then the type then typescript defaults  to type `any` for key and value type parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypeScript's type system operates primarily under the restriction that values have a type that does not change over time.   So if you write `let a: string = "hey";`, you're telling the compiler that `a` is *and will always be* a `string`.  You can't later write `a = 4;` without a compile-time error.  If you just write `let b = "hey";` without annotating the type, the compiler will *infer* the type as `string`, and again, later if you write `b = 4;` you will get a compiler error.  If you want a variable to hold a `string` sometimes and a `number` other times, you should annotate it yourself as `string | number` when you declare it, as in `let c: string | number = "hey";` and then `c = 4;` will be okay.

By default, then, if you have an object, you will need to tell the compiler in advance what the property types are going to be, when you declare it.  So the following will give you an error:

```
let o = {}; // type {}
o.a = new A('a'); // error, {} has no "a" property
o.b = new A(1); // error, {} has no "b" property
```

and the following will work:

```
let o2 = { a: new A('a'), b: new A(1) }; // okay
// let o2: { a: A<string>; b: A<number>; }
```

---

One feature of TypeScript that makes this restriction easier to deal with is [control flow type analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#control-flow-based-type-analysis), where the compiler sees something that temporarily *narrows* the type of a value by *restricting it to a subtype*.  If I write `let c: string | number = "hey"` I can then write `c.toUpperCase()` without error, because the compiler sees that the assignment has temporarily narrowed `c` from `string | number` to `string`.  Without such analysis, then you'd need to use a type assertion like `(c as string).toUpperCase()`. But even control flow type analysis can't change the type of a value arbitrarily; it can only narrow it (or possibly re-widen back to the annotated/inferred type upon reassignment).  So you can use this to add properties to objects, but not to change the type of properties or even delete a property.  If you want to be able to delete a property, then you need the property you add to be optional when you add it.

TypeScript 3.7 introduced [assertion functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#assertion-functions) which allow user-defined functions that customize the control flow based narrowing of their arguments.  You can use this to write a custom `setProp` function that adds properties to an existing object.  Since I know you want to delete the properties, I will make it add them as optional:

```
function setProp<O extends object, K extends PropertyKey, V>(
    obj: Partial<O>,
    key: Exclude<K, keyof O>, value: V
): asserts obj is Partial<O & Record<K, V>> {
    (obj as any)[key] = value as any;
}
```

It works like this:

```
const map = {}
map.a = new A('a'); // error, can't do this
// but can do this:
setProp(map, 'a', new A('a'));
// now that it's been set you can re-set it to the same type
map.a = new A('b');

setProp(map, 'b', new A(1));
setProp(map, 'c', "a string");
```

You can get and delete properties with just property access, keeping in mind that since they are deletable, you need to check for `undefined` before accessing them:

```
map.a && console.log(map.a.value); // b
map.b && console.log(map.b.value); // 1
delete map.b; // okay        
map.c && console.log(map.c.toUpperCase()); // A STRING
```

So this is how I might go about it.  Still, it's better to just set the types ahead of time when you declare the `map`.  Control-flow based narrowing is less robust than just annotating the type to start with.

---

Finally, if you really want to use a `Map` instead of a plain object, you could write your own custom typings for `Map`, since the built-in `Map` typings assume all the values will be of the same type.  But this is already really long. In the Playground Link below I have a possible implementation along with the rest of the code from the above.

Okay, hope this helps give you some ideas.  Good luck!

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVAfNA3gKGt6wD2AdhAC4BOArsMXqQBQAO5ARiAJbDQBuYI5ApgC5oiAJTpoAXwxSMZAJ7osOEH2LQwQkqVYEA5tAC80AEQALPnOMBuJdjCHoAFivQA9K+h9SpGregq1JgczC2s-IKNnNw8vH1I-ANxNMh19AB9oAnIAWyYvYPNLGxxcByj3aDwAazA5DATVSoc0CRcK4jl6PnQpErwAOnsjAj4AdzhaAHIwSZE2mO8aABoe6FNITLwTMGNoeh8u0g6-AYjMsYmARjnoz0XSFZa1jYIt4yZd-bxD44a1PAATM11EIRuNYFMZiIVkxQRcIddJPNKjU6iUKolAUI0CC4PAtKlkC5YXisrkvETJPUShwjCEin5gP1qABVeiHADCkD4tBuFWqtUZZWKOCZrPZXi5EB5fIWcXqElwYGIwFM0FofDEmGk9QwBDA2T4EHoYGA3QACuAdAB5JgAKz4VEUfgAZuQCFRWIRoNLiOaDvBrZ4AB7EPgEAAmMDw9sdxBWAGkQ2HIzB-d8vB0ExYVgA1ZC0Px9e1Cc1gI6sHiB5BLIs4KoWIQAUWDoHIEb48ATKwbcjwLug1prXB4-CEub8IiEkGlR2j9ugrDT5eIlZAgegADJoAAlR00CNdvPIVCYEolWgxu3qGBgAhyEQAbV7AF0HNxeN0Nne5CLsDIaUIEhoGyMB6GaXocFA+hBgcMEJmmWZkViZYlQISY1AjLZiFMJc-AqJhyDUYA72gLDoBwpcBD8X103oWhoJWRCVngiFEJEOZqRwCpXnGHDlUXYhJhgPJwx9Ro+3INDoFIPgAFpfUEijsPMH0DW6Douj8aDYOGeEpiYJCuOwWiDgYsCmMMlj9OuTiSlM75zPoJjgEmFZjHsAk9GMTjtLA2DN23fAiDwFR+hAPBdCcwZ+g-fhZWgJg-JgoJAtwIDQr4cLIuiphYtHTVkUuPwOwCbodKYZEBQUc9sGS-oODS4KIEy7Kop0sU8DZTluV5BLYGgABlRAdwASQAOQAcWgBV6n1Q1jVNbpBtUa0CBAOQAFkwMUEodDDUgXSW6BtvoDc+FDcMo0qWMnSMFpTzrbBdFULtkyumBe37QcC17IQEynQdHwTF8-3PX03oulNrrozM5GzORj0LWrar+6AWzbDsj2gL6ByHWsUfPOLBGgCdCcBmdMxgSiYCXE6wPgHFH3NRcCGgJMMlxwcX1Ld7U3Z6AAH5SegXmoY+nGLG+oNhetZm33HSQiSe8TiEhy7+a5odaDR7sR0-IQ5ZBwHODwVgIzBkpZLALD1oUCBWAALxJsk8lIMHIOwDtQHLbpmrUU64XGXlDFQU6bEZIC1GgoRTrgi5Tt5MGdN9SE3POcE0445P-NTyYrIzq5s-qvPXPczyUm83zAKINQhhA-yXuILOwea1qIqisB8s-BKwEj2vEocHSm4Moya5asKO9oPLiYS4rx+IofG9UWhjGAHzW4yyecs67rJV67PbgG4axqm4zbleMMKPWNRJOkkZOHyd1FJoXB1j0L8KM6bpCDNQThNViXFea9jDuWqhvbAFRRg0CqDAIBzcQErEuACAAzDcW4KFSAAEIZo6jmupRaf8VrEGtKQAAInwMqcczw4H2l4I6f9TrnQ1tdK8cYIKPUJqVVQnYkzi01lLPGv1Gzs0BkwPAmU7yWxwE3dW0NPqCJ+jrERANDbAzfBkd0HYXQ6D4BbFWEM+EsLTAcOGCMkYqxKGjDGvAsZ6y1jWSxOBibjhVhTKAVNr50zpkwpmLMdAC05oo60PNoAs34ddJMwtcyizCXza6WshZA3NArEWEhlaE0MfEhRfYhHKLkP9FYLigbGyEKbc20jsDW1thtH0TsXY5Ddh7EqjpwCyXSgPQOhcQ4GDDmBCO-dgIx3puBPS4xE52SgrnFezFC5sShJM7AKcZkF1YrQWyOcYKl3Th5H0lddAb3Pv7dQS8YIj3YmDVgA5aBgDEG3bendu7xWRH3Beg8jDDxWWPWh1ymB3K3llKeM8Cpz0GYvD5y8EHr0WYua5wB-khQebQXeEpSBShlP1IaI0JqTXPssqFoCTDgPQVAmBcCSg6W4WGVe0KqqonqiPEBIhZpAA)

Comment: Similar to how Arrays have gotten [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html), I hope Map will get more accurate typings in the future.